# How to improve the performance of SQL Query with Group-By?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, inner-join

I need a alternate query for below query (for improve the performance of query)-

```
;WITH products as (SELECT DISTINCT Id3 FROM Table1 WHERE id ='abcd-1234-adfasd')    


SELECT t2.TransactionId ,count(t2.TransactionId) 
FROM Table2 AS t2
inner JOIN products AS p ON (t2.Id3 = p.Id3)                                  
WHERE ( (t2.Id1 != 'ggg-bbbccc-ttt')
AND (t2.CreatedTime > '2016-10-12T12:21:37.5088739')AND (t2.CreatedTime <= '2016-10-12T12:23:17.7377845')) AND (t2.Id2=2) 
GROUP BY t2.TransactionId
ORDER BY TransactionId
```

In the above query the **count(t2.TransactionId)** is not giving the proper result and for that I replaced it by below sub query -

```
SELECT t2.TransactionId ,(select count(1) from Table2 where TransactionId = t2.TransactionId) as trunacount
FROM Table2 AS t2
inner JOIN products AS p ON (t2.Id3 = p.Id3)                                  
WHERE ( (t2.Id1 != 'ggg-bbbccc-ttt')
AND (t2.CreatedTime > '2016-10-12T12:21:37.5088739')AND (t2.CreatedTime <= '2016-10-12T12:23:17.7377845')) AND (t2.Id2=2) 
GROUP BY t2.TransactionId
ORDER BY TransactionId
```

And the above query is giving correct result but taking little bit long time as compare to first query. So I need a way where I can get the count of TransactionId in less time.

Below is the table structure of Table2 (there is no primary key in Table2)-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using Co-related Sub Query for Count column. I think this might be making performance issue. Because Co related Sub Queries will compare every record of inner set with every record of Outer set. My suggestion is to Replace it with LEFT JOIN.

```
    SELECT T2.TRANSACTIONID ,TRANS_COUNT.TRANSAC_COUNT AS TRUNACOUNT
    FROM TABLE2 AS T2
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS P ON (T2.ID3 = P.ID3) 

    LEFT JOIN  
    (
    SELECT TRANSACTIONID, COUNT(1) TRANSAC_COUNT FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY  TRANSACTIONID
    )   AS TRANS_COUNT ON    T2.TRANSACTIONID =     TRANS_COUNT.TRANSACTIONID  


    WHERE ( (T2.ID1 != 'GGG-BBBCCC-TTT')
    AND (T2.CREATEDTIME > '2016-10-12T12:21:37.5088739')
    AND (T2.CREATEDTIME <= '2016-10-12T12:23:17.7377845')) AND (T2.ID2=2) 
    GROUP BY T2.TRANSACTIONID
    ORDER BY TRANSACTIONID
```

If still performance lag then You could fetch only plain data into a Table variable(INSERT) Then you can do Count, Group By and Distinct on That Single Set (Table Variable).

Hope this will help you out!!